# Grouping layout elements toRightOf another group or element

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set a textview to the left of two other textviews. I thought that I might use some kind of container to group them apart and then set the first textview to the left of the container containing the other two textviews. But I'm not finding anything that works.

I tried using a relativelayout to group them together but it only seems to fill the whole screen width and makes the first textview to the left outside of the screen.

If I set the relativelayout that contains the two other textviews to right of the first textview it kinda works, but then if the text in it is too long in the first textview it will overlap the container and its content, which I don't want it to.

In the example below "textview1" will contain a longer string which could take 1-3 rows.
The other two will only contain a few characters but it's important that they are visible.

At first I had textview1 to the left of textview2 but sometimes textview3 will be wider than textview2 which causes problems.

Any ideas how to fix this?

See image at link below of how it should look vs how it does look right now as requested.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d5o4.png

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#111"
        android:background="#FF9999">
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:background="#99FF99">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:background="#9999FF">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the image of expected and current output.

Comment: Image added. Available at http://i.stack.imgur.com/1d5o4.png

Comment: What is that? expected output?

Comment: The image contains two parts. One at the top which is what I'm after and one below the black line which is what I currently get. I want all TextViews to be visible and ordered correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the layout, just play around with height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="0.2"
     >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#00ff00"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000ff"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: This is usable. Thanks. I'm wondering if it's possible to instead of width in percent it is possible somehow to wrap_content. But it might not be.

Comment: Screen size of Android mobiles vary, so it is better to go with weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Give the width and height for Textview1 

for example


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/textview01_layout"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#FF9999"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="parthi"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#99FF99"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="parthi"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#9999FF"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="parthi"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```